# fetching data from different tables based on different joins in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the query returns perfect results when `invstorelocation`.`Description` AS Location , is not included in the query along with the join

```
    INNER JOIN 
    `invstorelocation`
 ON (`invlabtes`.`StockLocCode` = `invstorelocation`.`Code`)
```

But when I include this join in the query the table returns empty even though all conditions are fully met. Plz mention the alternative to fetch Location record along with other records.

```
 SELECT 
`invlabtes`.`CommAppCode` , 
`invlabtes`.`Code` , 
`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` , 
`invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` , 
`invlabtes`.`SupplierCode` , 
`invstorelocation`.`Description` AS Location , 
`invstore`.`Description` AS MaterialName 
FROM 
    `invlabtes` 
INNER JOIN 
    `invstorelocation`
 ON (`invlabtes`.`StockLocCode` = `invstorelocation`.`Code`)        
INNER JOIN 
    `invgatepass` 
ON (`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` = `invgatepass`.`InwardNo`) AND (`invlabtes`.`GatePassDate` = `invgatepass`.`EntryDate`) AND (`invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` = `invgatepass`.`VehicleNo`)

 INNER JOIN 
    `invgatepasssubtable` 
ON (`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` = `invgatepasssubtable`.`InwardNo`) AND (`invlabtes`.`ItemCode` = `invgatepasssubtable`.`ItemCode`) 

INNER JOIN 
    `invstore` 
ON (`invgatepass`.`StoreCode` = `invstore`.`Code`) 

 WHERE (`invlabtes`.`Code` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`CommAppCode` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`SupplierCode` LIKE '%%') AND `invlabtes`.`CommAppCode`<>'' AND `invlabtes`.`Unit_Code`='1' LIMIT 100;
```

This query successfully returns   the data. The above query has problem.

```
  SELECT 
`invlabtes`.`CommAppCode` , 
`invlabtes`.`Code` , 
`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` , 
`invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` , 
`invlabtes`.`SupplierCode` ,  
`invstore`.`Description` AS MaterialName 
FROM 
    `invlabtes` 

INNER JOIN 
    `invgatepass` 
ON (`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` = `invgatepass`.`InwardNo`) AND (`invlabtes`.`GatePassDate` = `invgatepass`.`EntryDate`) AND (`invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` = `invgatepass`.`VehicleNo`)

 INNER JOIN 
    `invgatepasssubtable` 
ON (`invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` = `invgatepasssubtable`.`InwardNo`) AND (`invlabtes`.`ItemCode` = `invgatepasssubtable`.`ItemCode`) 

INNER JOIN 
    `invstore` 
ON (`invgatepass`.`StoreCode` = `invstore`.`Code`) 

 WHERE (`invlabtes`.`Code` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`CommAppCode` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`GatePassNO` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`VehicleNo` LIKE '%%' OR `invlabtes`.`SupplierCode` LIKE '%%') AND `invlabtes`.`CommAppCode`<>'' AND `invlabtes`.`Unit_Code`='1' LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Are you sure you know what this query is supposed to do?

Comment: yes this query is fetching data from invlabtes table and invstore table on basis of matching entries in invgatepass table and invgatepasssubtable. I also want to fetch corresponding location description from invstorelocation table

Comment: There's really no way for us to investigate without having your data as well.  I'm sorry, but if you're not geting any rows, then clearly all conditions are ***not*** fully met.  DBs don't just refuse to show data.  The conditions include the conditions of the join, and the only way to figure  it out is to dig in and figure out why the conditions aren't met when you add the join.  That might be easier to do by changing that join that causes it to fail to an outer join and looking at the records.

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you say at face value, it would appear that there are no `invstorelocation` rows where the `invstorelocation.Code` matches an `invlabtes.StockLocCode` value for the restrictions you've specified.

Try selecting just `invlabtes.StockLocCode` 
i.e.  `SELECT invlabtesFROM StockLocCode`

Then try selecting `Code` from `invstorelocation`
i.e. `SELECt Code FROM invstorelocation`

Check if any values correspond, and if they do, chekc if they've been filtered out by the WHERE clause?

Unfortunately without the data this would be hard to diagnose.

Comment: sir plz read the question again. the invstore has no problem in query. only the `invstorelocation`.`description` does not return data. when the query is run without this single join then it returns successful matches. Only problem is with `invstorelocation`

Comment: I'll amend my recommendation accordingly, but it's the same advice, just different tables / columns...

Comment: Sorry I the name of table was wrong the correct name was    invunloadinglocation and not the invstorelocation.

Comment: No problem - the kind of mistake, anyone could make ;) - Do feel freen to answer your own question and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
`invstorelocation`
ON (`invlabtes`.`StockLocCode` = `invstorelocation`.`Code`)
```

If using INNER JOIN and the table is empty, it will return no results

Comment: It worked when I tried your solution (I got null values in Location field in resultset). but the issue is that the table `invstorelocation` is not empty and it has corresponding entries in it. I have manually checked this. Please mention where I am wrong in fomulating the query or am I making a wrong logic in query.

Comment: My problem is solved The query runs successfully now

The problem was

The Name of table was invunloadinglocation and I was using a wrong name i.e invstorelocation Thanx to everyone who replied